# Simple css opacity IE fix help needed

Tags: css, opacity

Please [compare this page](http://girisoft.net/ie/) in chrome and IE

You can see drop down fields in the right side.

In chrome it displays correctly. But in IE displays rectangular boxes.

So i applied opacity for select fields using the following code.

```
select
{
opacity:0;
filter:alpha(opacity=0); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

But it hides everything. I mean "Please select" text too. You can see everything invisible in IE but chrome displays it correctly.

So i tried this code. But its not working.

```
select option.selectedx
{
opacity:1;
filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Where `selectedx` is the class name of my drop down selected field.

Thanks

Comment: Won't work, as the parent's opacity is the child's opacity.

Comment: Is there any other way there to fix this problem?

Comment: Look at implementations of this, specifically jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) property